# How to count something repeated in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to count the number of employee each manager supervises.
Here is my current SQL:

```
SELECT LAST_NAME as 'Supervisor Last Name', COUNT(SUPERIOR_EMP_ID)
FROM Banking.Employee
GROUP BY LAST_NAME
HAVING COUNT(SUPERIOR_EMP_ID) = 1;
```

I want to get below table. Count = Number of the same Superior_Emp_ID

---

```
Supervisor Last Name| Count
-----------------------------------
Smith               | 2

John                | 4

Williams            | 4
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
SELECT e1.Last_Name, count(e.emp_id) EmployeeCount FROM Banking.Employee e join Banking.Employee e1 on e.SUPERIOR_EMP_ID = e1.emp_id GROUP BY e1.SUPERIOR_EMP_ID, e1.Last_Name
```

*Note: I am assuming your have emp_id primary key column in the employee table*

Comment: This only shows count = 1 for all. So I want count to count SUPERIOR_EMP_ID. How do I show Smith has 2 employees, and Tyler has 3, etc.

Comment: Please share the table structure with some sample data

Comment: @Alex - try the updated query, you should should self join to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

for us to have safe group by, lets group by `superior_emp_id` instead of `last_name`, might me some duplicates on `last_name`.

```
select t.Last_name, t1.ct from 
Employee t 
inner join
    (select superior_emp_id, count(1) as ct
    from Employee 
    group by superior_emp_id) t1 on t1.superior_emp_id = t.superior_emp_id
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks!